# video background revolution slider

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

Is there a way to have a full screen video show through all the different slides?  I have tried the global / static settings and have not been able to setup the video so that it is full screen / cover.

I was thinking that setting the video as the background using CSS might do the trick.

Any other ideas?